# Oracle SQL - Free Text Search

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search

I'm implementing a kind of Catalog Search (Item Search), but I want to support searches with partial information, specially to support searches with Item Description, so users could type in part of the Item Description.

I want to support something like:

port = S**port**s 
sup**port** 
**Port** 
**port**able

123 = NES89-**123**9989 
**123**9948993HD-08 
767-OIJD-189**123**-09OI

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column you are searching is called `TXT`, and the input string is a bind variable with name `:SEARCH_STR`, you need to include `WHERE INSTR(TXT, :SEARCH_STR) > 0` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Use "like" comparison.

example:

```
select *
from tbl
where my_data like '%port%';
```